# perl telnet - how to handle multiple pages of output

Tags: perl, telnet, multipage

I'm writing a script for saving the switch configuration via save the output "show run" because in firmware has problems with working through tftp.
The output of "show run" is divided by posts `More: <space>, Quit: q, One line: <return>`.

```
# sh run
no spanning-tree
interface port-channel 1
shutdown
exit
interface port-channel 2
shutdown
exit
interface port-channel 3
shutdown
exit
interface port-channel 4
shutdown
exit
interface port-channel 5
shutdown
exit
interface port-channel 6
shutdown
exit
interface port-channel 7
shutdown
exit
More: <space>,  Quit: q, One line: <return>
```

Part of my script below:

```
foreach (@linksys_sps){
  print ("Connecting to ",$_,"\n");
  my $telnet = new Net::Telnet ( Timeout=>10,Errmode=>'return');
  $telnet->open($_);
  if ($telnet->errmsg){
    print "Can't connect to " . $_ . " Error: " . $telnet->errmsg . "\n";
  } else {
    $telnet->waitfor('/User Name:$/i');
    $telnet->print('admin');
    $telnet->waitfor('/Password:$/i');
    $telnet->print('password');
    my @lines = $telnet->cmd("sh run");
    print @lines;
    sleep(5);
    $telnet->print('exit');
  }
}
```

and the result of his work:

```
# sh run
no spanning-tree
interface port-channel 1
shutdown
exit
interface port-channel 2
shutdown
exit
interface port-channel 3
shutdown
exit
interface port-channel 4
shutdown
exit
interface port-channel 5
shutdown
exit
interface port-channel 6
shutdown
exit
interface port-channel 7
shutdown
exit
More: <space>,  Quit: q, One line: <return>
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there an option on your switch to set page length to zero (0)?  If so you'd have to add that before performing the 'sh run' command.

Answer (score 0):

On alcatel 6224 and same Dell powerconnect 3548 it works:

```
my @lines = $telnet->cmd("terminal datadump");
@lines = $telnet->cmd("show run");
```